# variable is only used once

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

I am using ancient Turbo Prolog since it is included in our curriculum. Why is this program not working?

```
domains
    disease, indication = symbol
    Patient = string
    Fe,Ra,He,Ch,Vo,Ru = char
predicates
    hypothesis(Patient,disease)
    symptom(Patient,indication,char)
    response(char)
    go
clauses


    go:-

        write("What is patient's name?"),
        readln(Patient),

        symptom(Patient,fever,Fe),
        symptom(Patient,rash,Ra),   
        symptom(Patient,head_ache,He),  
        symptom(Patient,chills,Ch), 


        symptom(Patient,runny_nose,Ru),
        symptom(Patient,head_ache,He),  
        symptom(Patient,vomit,Vo),


        hypothesis(Patient,Disease),
        write(Patient," probably has ", Disease , "."),nl.

    go:-
        write("Sorry unable to seem to be diagnose disease"),nl.

    symptom(Patient,Fever,Feedback) :-
        Write("Does " , Patient , " have " , Fever , "(y/n) ?"),
        response(Reply),
        Feedback = Reply.


    hypothesis(Patient, chicken_pox) :-

        Fe = Ra = He = Ch = 'y'.

    hypothesis(Patient, caner) :-
        Ru = Ra = He = Vo = 'y'.

    hypothesis(Patient, measles) :-
        Vo = Ra = Ch = Fe = He = 'y'.

    response(Reply):-
        readchar(Reply),
        write(Reply),nl.
```

I get the warning variable is only used at all lines which contains `symtoms`. Isn't the parameter passing call by reference? When i pass `Fe` to `symptoms` the value should be copied to `Fe` and when i compare it in hypothesis it should work accordingly. `=` operator in Turbo Prolog works very strangely. When it is not bound to any variable, the statement `a = 3` will assign 3 to a and when a already contains a value `a = 5` will check whether a's value is 5 or not.

Kindly help me why is the program not working?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am not experienced in Turbo Prolog but in "normal" prolog `=` is doing exactly what it should. `=` is not about arithmetic evaluation but about unification, `LHS = RHS` tries to **unify** `LHS` and `RHS` and binding any variables in either as necessary.

Comment: @rvirding , you are right about unification. But the rule for `=` is if the variable is unbound, `=` will act as assignment operator and if it is bound meaning it contains some value, then `=` will act as comparison operator.

Comment: Yes, but what you are describing **is** unification, or at least at a simple level. The variables can be within nested terms. So with `foo(X) = foo(3)` then the variable `X` will be unified with `3`, either bound or matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is not with your `symptoms/3` predicate, they will bind (unify) their 3rd argument to what `response/1` gives. The problem is that these values are never passed into your `hypothesis/2` procedure in `go/0` so they are never used to try and generate a hypothesis. Prolog doesn't have global variables so you have to explicitly pass all values, though you can keep things in the database which can easily cause problems if you are not careful.

This means that in `hypothesis/2` you are not testing the values of `Fe`, `Ra`, `He`, etc but binding **local** variables with the same names. This is also why you get warnings of the variables only being referenced once, you bind them but never use them. Remember they are local, all variables are local to the clause in which they occur.

All this applies to standard prolog, I have never used Turbo Prolog.